# Visual Studio 2010 for UI wireframe?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Just wanted to know that how good is the Visual Studio 2010 for designing UI wireframe?
Is there any major shortcoming in VS2010 in this area.
The UI that i am going to create are the mock up UI but i intend to use the same in future for actual web application development.

Please help, as i am going to use it for the above mention work .

Comment: Do you mean just mocking up forms? if so, then its a RAD too so you can just drag and drop controls onto a new windows application to screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use visio or any other Mockup tool, see here: http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/18-great-examples-of-sketched-ui-wireframes-and-mockups

I don't think Visual Studio alone without any AddIn would be very useful in this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a microsoft product why not use sketchflow http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow_Overview.aspx
AS you may already have blend installed.

Answer (score 2):

I've started using the Balsamiq mock-up tool for quick prototypes, it's good for that early mock-screen stage but it might be too simple for what you want.

http://balsamiq.com/

There is a web-demo you can try, my favourite feature about it is that it doesn't look like a finished product so it keeps things looking suitably "prototypey".  I've tried sketchflow after watching the incredible demo video but it was much buggier and unreliable when I tried it for myself and I spent more time fighting with it than I did coding so I just ditched it and went back to the Balsamiq tool.